# How to select from text list randomly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function, string-function

I'm trying to build SQL function that I can use as a default value for a column. The function is about selecting an avatar image path randomly if the user didn't assign an image.

I have tried to but a completely wrong example to just approach the image not the solution

what I need to do is something like this

```
select top 1 from "avatar1,png, avatar2,png, avatar3.png, avatar4.png, avatar5.png"  order by rand();
```

and I will convert it to a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReturnAvatar() 
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret nvarchar(100);  
        SET @ret = (select top 1 from "avatar1,png, avatar2,png, avatar3.png, avatar4.png, avatar5.png" as tbl order by rand());  
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

this is just to explain the idea that I'm not able to apply. I don't know if SQL server has something like this or not.

Comment: What is your SQl Server version?

Comment: `avatar1,png` Is the comma a typo?

Comment: @HoneyBadger  yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a table at all. Simply put the number inside your string and choose the number randomly:

```
select 'avatar'+str(round(rand()*5+1,0))+'.png'
```

would be fine.

Put that into your function and you are all set.

`rand()` produces 0..1(excl.) so you can simply multiply it by 5 and add 1 to get your range of 1...5

Demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/82866

---

Documentation:

- [ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [STR ( float_expression [, length [, decimal]])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [rand(seed)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

So essentially you could boil it down to:

```
 select 'avatar'+ltrim(str(rand()*5+1,20,0))+'.png'
```

with

- [ltrim(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) taking care of the space

Comment: it's simple and great way. it was having space in the result but it's ok I replaced it (SELECT REPLACE((select 'avatar'+str(round(rand()*5+1,0))+'.png'), ' ', '') ). However, if you have time to add some explanation for the included functions that would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA added the functions, removed `round()` as you can do this inside `str()` and introduces `trim()` to eleminate the space in front of the number. hth.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
CREATE VIEW getNewID AS SELECT newid() as new_id

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReturnAvatar() 
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret nvarchar(100);  
        SET @ret = (SELECT TOP 1 value
                    FROM
                        STRING_SPLIT('avatar1.png,avatar2.png,avatar3.png,avatar4.png,avatar5.png', ',')
                    ORDER BY (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID));
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Note that your current CSV string of filenames does not seem proper, because comma does not indicate the start of the extension in either Windows or Linux.  So, I have assumed dot everywhere.  In addition, if you want to use `STRING_SPLIT`, you may only split on a single character.  Therefore, I assume that comma will be the delimiter here.

Comment: You might want to add some explanation as to why you order via a view. It took me a bit longer than I'm willing to admit.

Answer (score 0):

```
create function dbo.ReturnAvatar(@uid uniqueidentifier, @avatars int = 10)
returns varchar(100)
as 
begin 
    return ('avatar' + cast(abs(checksum(@uid)) % isnull(abs(@avatars), 10)+1 as varchar(100)) + '.png')
end
go

create table myusers
(
username varchar(50),
theavatar varchar(100) default( dbo.ReturnAvatar(newid(), default))
);

insert into myusers(username)
select top (10000) 'user' + cast(row_number() over(order by(select null)) as varchar(50))
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b;
go

select theavatar, count(*)
from myusers
group by theavatar;
go

drop table myusers;
```